# Paperclip's attachment to be in UUID instead of natural id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have a table model that has uuid as its primary key and it has a paperclip attachment.
When I upload the file, it gets truncated into 3 folder with 3 characters e.g.
uuid of 18ac5169-1104-486a-862b-ab760523a096 will become 18a/c51/69-/original/image.png

is there a way to configure paperclip to store the whole UUID instead of the truncated version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you are having is a result of the url using the `:id_partition` interpolation, which splits the `id` into 3 character split path form for the first 9 characters.

I suspect this is because you haven't supplied a url option and Paperclip is using the default of:

```
/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename
```

To override this you need to specify the `url` option and replace `:id_partition` with the `:id` interpolation instead. In your model that has the attachment change the `has_attached_file` declaration to:

```
has_attached_file :my_attachment,
                    url: '/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename'
```

naturally changing `:my_attachment` to what you current have.